# Why is the "wind triangle" an instructional method for solving Wind Correction Angle problems?

Tags: crosswind, ground-instructor

When solving a wind correction problem, what are the benefits of graphing wind speed/direction, true course, and true airspeed? Any digital calculator would be quicker; even the E6B would be faster (given that one is proficient).

I feel the graph method helps develop, over time, a better situational awareness when dealing with all sorts of crosswind problems and solving those problems on a "gut level."

However, for some reason, it sounds too simple to be the "proper" explanation from a pedagogical perspective.

**Edit:**
Changed "But this sounds like hardly the "proper" reason for using graphs." to
"However, for some reason, it sounds too simple to be the "proper" explanation from a pedagogical perspective.
"

Comment: Why do we still teach math in school when we have calculators that can do it for us?

Comment: I'm not sure what more you can expect from an answer than your second paragraph... (removing the frankly quite depressing last sentence - if wanting to understand things is no longer a "proper" reason to do things, what are we even doing here?)

Comment: Well, the E6b *is* a graphical method of solving the crosswind problem, right?  It's just handy way to draw the wind triangle, right?  You just aren't physically including the full lengths of all the arrows.

Comment: @Sanchises, I just had to ask myself if the answer is that simple? The question touches on best practices of teaching subjects like physics, and come to think of it, a CFI is also a science teacher. So I stopped and wondered, "Why the graph?" End I revised the last sentence as well. The original one was pretty grim.

Comment: @quietflyer, yes, the E6b is on the graphical side. I just find it difficult to look at the gray pencil marks on the rotating disc. And it's not as obvious as a drown out graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need to make sure that you understand the concepts of what’s going on. It’s true that the digital calculator or digital East 6B can solve those problems for you, but that makes you susceptible to GIGO or Garbage In = Garbage Out. It’s very easy to make mistakes and erroneous calculations if you don’t understand what you are entering and if you don’t know what to expect from it.

Vector graphs are an excellent mathematical tool for visualizing what’s going on and how an aircraft’s flight path is affected by winds aloft.  You are correct that’s it’s not practical to perform this in the cockpit of an airplane while flying, but performing this on the ground gives you a much better sense of how winds affect you so you can use this to assess answers generated by

As an example, suppose you want to fly a true course of 280°.  The local winds at altitude are 210° True at 13 knots.  Your airplane flies at 150 KTAS.  By the numbers you’ll notice that we’ll have a light to moderate crosswind with a slight headwind component.  Using some basic judgment we estimate we should see a heading of ~3-5° short of our intended course and maybe ~5-10 kts slower groundspeed.

And in fact, if we compute this on an E6B, we find a desired heading of 275° True, with a WCA of -5°, and a groundspeed of 145 knots.  That seems pretty close to what we anticipated, so we can use our knowledge of wind correction and effects to conclude that the calculation we performed in the answers we got are accurate.

Comment: ...and you only know those approximations _because_ you've visualised it previously on an E6B or similar. If you've only ever plugged the numbers into a digital tool of some sort you have no idea what it's supposed to be. So you can't "sense check" it.

Answer (score 5):

Because if you don't provide explanations like this ([Why does the airplane not 'feel' the crosswind?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27158/why-does-the-airplane-not-feel-the-crosswind/27159#27159)), then people will be left with misunderstandings like this ([Why does the airplane not 'feel' the crosswind?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27158/why-does-the-airplane-not-feel-the-crosswind)).

Because vector diagrams are very simple and easy to understand, and are at the heart of the basic physics of motion, which is highly relevant to flight.  Same reason we expect every pilot to be able to draw the basic Lift-Drag-Thrust-Weight diagram for level flight, gliding flight, climbing flight, etc.  If they couldn't draw those diagrams correctly, they'd be in danger of crashing.

Or at the very least, they'd be robbed of the chance to  understand and appreciate one aspect of the beauty of flight.